# Trigger Azure Logic App on the third business day of every month

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-logic-apps, recurrence

I'm having problems designing recurrence triggers with logic apps. As far as I know, the logic apps do not support CRON expressions, and running a daily trigger with conditions does not seem to be enough, so I am totally at an loss.

Edit:

To be more precise about my problem, The logic app is for moving files from one server to other and outside constraints dictate that this move should be completed once every month, and the move should happen on the third business day (monday-friday) of the month.

I'm currently pondering on either saving a global variable to tell me whether the app has succesfully ran this month, and using conditions to check every day whether it should run on the day, or starting the running a script which determines if current date is the third weekday of current month, and using that to determine if the logic app should execute or terminate.

Comment: I doubt if we can achieve this easily just by using `Recurrence Trigger` .. but you may add the logic into javascript code and use that `Inline Javascript` code as step to make your decision ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three major options I can see, two of which I would entertain the thought of here.  Main reason, due to cost, I've left out the use of the `Inline Javascript` action because it requires an integration account which will incur substantially more cost than either of the options below.

#### Prerequisites

The trigger should be a recurrence every day.  It will still need to run, it's just whether or not it does anything.  There's no getting away from that.

Initialise a variable of type `String` with the current date.  I've included a formula that takes UTC and converts it to your local timezone, you'd just need to change it accordingly.

`convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'AUS Eastern Standard Time')`

[image: ICD]

#### Option 1 - Azure Function

An Azure Function is by far the easiest way.  Create a .NET function app (or whatever language you're comfortable with but you won't be able to use the code below) and from there, create a function with the following code called `GetBusinessDayOfMonthForDate` ...

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    DateTime dateToProcess = DateTime.Parse(req.Query["Date"]);
    
    int businessDayCount = 0;
    var tempDate = dateToProcess;

    while (tempDate.Month == dateToProcess.Month)
    {                    
        businessDayCount += (tempDate.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 1) != "S") ? 1 : 0;
        tempDate = tempDate.AddDays(-1);
    }

    return new OkObjectResult(businessDayCount.ToString());
}
```

Now call that from Logic Apps directly after the previous action ...

[image: Action]

[image: AFResult]

#### Option 2 - Standard Actions

The basic premise of this approach is the same as the Azure Function but naturally, it's a lot more long winded.

This is the JSON definition for that approach, it includes everything you need to test it in your own environment.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {},
                "else": {
                    "actions": {
                        "Terminate": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "runStatus": "Cancelled"
                            },
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "Terminate"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@variables('Business Days Up to Today')",
                                3
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Until_Day_Index_=_-5": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "Initialize_Business_Days_Up_to_Today": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Business Days Up to Today",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Temp_Date": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Current_Date": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Current Date",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@{convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'AUS Eastern Standard Time')}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Day_Index": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Day Index",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Business_Days_Up_to_Today": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Temp_Date": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Temp Date",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@variables('Current Date')"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Current_Date": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Until_Day_Index_=_-5": {
                "actions": {
                    "Decrement_Current_Date": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Temp Date",
                            "value": "@{addDays(variables('Current Date'), variables('Day Index'))}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    },
                    "Decrement_Day_Index": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Day Index",
                            "value": 1
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Increment_variable": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "DecrementVariable"
                    },
                    "Increment_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Business Days Up to Today",
                            "value": "@if(and(greaterOrEquals(dayOfWeek(variables('Temp Date')), 1), lessOrEquals(dayOfWeek(variables('Temp Date')), 6)), 1, 0)"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Decrement_Current_Date": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "IncrementVariable"
                    }
                },
                "expression": "@equals(variables('Day Index'), -5)",
                "limit": {
                    "count": 60,
                    "timeout": "PT1H"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Day_Index": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Until"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

[image: Flow]

At the base all of that, throw in a condition to check if the current business day variable equals 3, if it does, run your logic.

That's included in the JSON definition above.

One of those approach is what I'd be doing so I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.

Comment: @Wampie, I'm curious to know which approach you used?

Comment: I decided to go with with the Azure Function approach, mainly because it leaves the actual logic app pretty clean for anyone who might need to work on it in the future. I did contemplate running a variable on a storage account that would stop the scrip from running once the logic app at completed any given month, but in the end decided against it, since It didn't give enough savings to be worth. it.

Comment: @Wampie, agreed, much cleaner.  I'd do the same.  The long winded approach was far too much to maintain in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recurrence trigger` in the logic app to trigger the workflow for every three weeks on Monday .

[image]

For more information about recurrence trigger you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence) documentation.

---

**Updated Answer:**

As per the requirement, we have created a logic app with recurrence as a trigger & frequency as day. This workflow  will fires every day and will validates whether current date is in between (3,4,5) or not.
if the condition is succeeded it will further executes the logic app actions.

**Here is the logic app that we have created:**

[image]

**Here is the code view of the logic app:**

```html
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'dd')",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": "@utcNow()",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "or": [
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@int(outputs('Compose_2'))",
                                3
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@int(outputs('Compose_2'))",
                                4
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@int(outputs('Compose_2'))",
                                5
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "schedule": {
                        "hours": [
                            "17"
                        ],
                        "minutes": [
                            16
                        ]
                    },
                    "startTime": "2021-12-28T17:14:00",
                    "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "startTime": "2021-12-28T17:14:00",
                    "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

**Note:**
Execution of logic app on every day may result in more billing & also logic app doesn't support any CORN expressions. In these scenarios it is suggested to use Azure time trigger functions instead of logic app.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant. I need the third weekday of each month, so it can be any day from monday to friday, and happen on 3rd, 4th or 5th day of the month.


I'm already kind of given up on easy solutions so now I'm looking for a way to check if date is 3, 4 or 5, and a weekday, and the logic app has not ran yet.

Comment: @Wampie - please go through the above updated answer & revert back if there are any issues.

Comment: I updated my original question to be more precise. But basically the logic app should execute it's logic (moving files) only once per month. The day of the month that happens should be the third business day (monday-friday) of that month.