# Power Automate - Monthly flow but only on 5th business day

Tags: power-automate

I am a Power BI user, but new to Power Automate.  I have a Power BI dashboard in the cloud and want to create a Power Automate flow to execute the Power BI subscription on the 5th business day of each month, so I need to exclude weekends and holidays.  Is this possible to do in Power Automate?  Do I need to create an Excel calendar and store it somewhere for the flow to read it?  If so, where do I store this file? Or do I need to create a Sharepoint List?  Thanks for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger Azure Logic App on the third business day of every month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503874/trigger-azure-logic-app-on-the-third-business-day-of-every-month)

Comment: Unfortunately not.  It does not factor in the fact that a holiday can fall on a weekday, and if that scenario happens, that date should not be included

Comment: Holidays are country specific and state specific in some cases.  It'll never be able to handle that nicely unless you can nominate what the holidays are so yes, best bet is to have it all setup in a spreadsheet or something.

Comment: There are many APIs that generate a list of holidays. You could JSON yourself a list inside a `compose` action for all the holidays you care about for the next 20 years.  I would avoid doing anything in a spreadsheet :)

Comment: @Muppet Bear.  Thanks for the tip about using a JSON file.  Do you know of one I can use that will tell me all the US Bank holidays?  Thanks

Comment: https://www.chicagofed.org/utilities/about-us/bank-holidays

Comment: @Muppet Bear.  Thanks for the info.  I'm not familiar much with API calls, but I tried to get this file in JSON format to use in a flow.  I opened my browser and pasted the url and suffixed it with .json but get an error message.  Is this available in JSON?  and don't I need an API key, and if so where do I get one?  What would the syntax of the call look like?  thanks

Comment: To clarify - My suggestion is to simply hardcode those dates into an array value inside a compose action, sourcing the dates from any number of the published web sources. This is sufficient for your use case, and trivial to setup and maintain. Alternatively, you can find a feed (odata, api, etc) to give you those dates - but that is clearly an overkill. 
What I very much advise to stay away from is feeding those dates from any sort of spreadsheet.

Comment: @Muppet Bear. Thanks. If I understand you correctly, you suggest I manually hardcode all the mnthly dates (going into the future) into an array inside of a compose action?.   I agree this should be easy.  I was hoping there is an easy way by maybe using an http activity to send a GET request to a site with the bank holiday information.  As an example for the UK holidays, the JSON file would be https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json.  An example of this is flow is https://chorus.co/resources/news/calculating-working-days-in-power-automate-or-logic-apps. This is what I am trying to do.Thx!//hbaww

Comment: @user19210181 - Yes, you got it. You also found a URL'ed json with the holidays. Just do an HTTP Get, form an array, or array of jsons, check your run dates to not exist in the array, if yes - continue, if not - exit. I think you have all the elements you need there, right? Go ahead and mark this one off as self-answered. :)

Comment: @Muppet Bear.  I am looking for a similar URL'ed JSON file but for US bank holidays, not UK holidays.  The sites you provided do show the dates, but there is no JSON file.  I prefer using a JSON file instead of hardcoding, as harcoding the dates will never pass a walk thru by my team.  Thanks!